# How can I use the Query String to return data from sql

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website for movies. If you click on a movie, it will take you to another page where it shows you all the details in that movie. Just think of it as an image for the movie and if you click on it the browser takes you to another page using the query string. Now, I have done all that but the problem is I can't show the requested information from the database. I need help to see what am doing wrong. Here is the html/asp.net code for the page with the different movie images

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repMovies" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repMovies_ItemDataBound" >
        <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="MovieDetail.aspx?MovieTitle=<%#Eval("ID") %>">
                     <main class="col-md-3 movie" style="background:#eee;margin-top:10px;padding:10px;border-radius:10px;border:solid 2px #333;height:280px;">
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="Images/<%#Eval ("Poster")  %>"  class=" img-responsive img-rounded" style="height:100px;width:100%"/>
                </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4"></div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h6><strong>Title:</strong><%#Eval("Title") %></h6>
                    </div>
                     <div class="row">
                       <h6><strong>Year :</strong><%#Eval("mYear") %></h6>
                    </div>
                     <div class="row">
                        <h6 style="font-size:9px;"><strong style="font-size:11px;">Starring:</strong><%#Eval("Starring") %></h6>
                    </div>
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="menu">
                            <h6 style="font-size:11px;"><strong>Summery:</strong></h6>
                          <p style="font-size:9px;"><%#Eval("Summary") %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
                </a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

and here the code behind the page of the Movie detail

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string movieId = Request.QueryString["ID"];
        repMovie.DataSource = db.Movies.Where(m => m.ID == movieId).ToList();
        repMovie.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: which part is not working,, do you get the movieID, or the result of linq

Comment: can you get the queryStrings value in code behind ? are you getting an error ? more details please.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong query string parameter name. As shown in the code snippet below, name of your query string parameter is `MovieTitle`. To get the movie id, you are trying to fetch it considering its name to be `ID` in your code behind `string movieId = Request.QueryString["ID"];`

```
<a href="MovieDetail.aspx?MovieTitle=<%#Eval("ID") %>">
```

Fetch the query string  in your code behind as shown below and you should be good:

```
string movieId = Request.QueryString["MovieTitle"];
```

Comment: It didn't work but if you can give me a way to contact you any way or you can call me on skype my name is Osama.Elayan93 please that would be a big help this is a graduation project and its due very close and I only have 2 to 3 major problems

Comment: What do you get in movieId variable when you execute this line of code `string movieId = Request.QueryString["MovieTitle"];`?

Comment: Also please feel free to raise questions on stackoverflow for your other 2-3 problems as well and give me the link to them. There is whole technological fraternity here round the clock who would be more than happy to help you.